# Append text from Javascript array with value pairs. Want to print out, only shows [Object, object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Append text from Javascript array with value pairs. Want to print out, only shows [Object, object]
See link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/akpn3/524/

```
var myFlashcards = [
{question:"Am I 24?",answer:"Yes"},{question:"Am I 6?",answer:"No"},{question:"When $a \\ne 0$, there are two solutions to \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\) and they are:",answer:"$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$"}
];
$('.listprice').append(myFlashcards.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this the one you want?

try use `JSON.stringify` to convert json <del>object</del> in order to show out

http://jsfiddle.net/akpn3/525/

Comment: there's no such thing as a json object. If it was already json, it would be string and you wouldn't need to stringify it

Comment: aha JSON.stringify, thanks, forgot to consider JSON methods, assumed it was only possible with JQuery /JS methods

Answer (score 0):

It's because called `toString()` to an `object` will returned `[Object object]`. Try with something like:

```
$.each(myFlashcards, function(i,n){
  $('.listprice').append('<div>'+n.question+'</div><div>'+n.answer+'</div>');
});
```

Or use stringify if you want to pretty print JSON-like string.

```
$('.listprice').append('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(myFlashCard)+'</pre>');
```

Comment: It's an object (`{}`) inside an array (`[]`). I think `myFlashcards[0].question` should be correct, changing the index to read all objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to read all objects inside the array, this should do it:

```
for (var element in myFlashcards)
{
    $('.listprice').append( '<p>' + element.question + ' ' + element.answer + '</p><br />' );
}
```